# How to create a procedural galia melon material?

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

I'm trying to create a procedural Galia melon texture, I want something like this as a result(with a bumpy look, yes) [image]
Any ideas?
[.Blend](http://%5B%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=qNQ4NKyk%22%20/%3E%5D(https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/qNQ4NKyk/)) File

Here's where I'm at now:
[image]
My node setup(sorry for the shitty pic):
[image]

**I can't use real melon images**

Comment: Hello :). You can also [share the .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) with your current node-setup.

Comment: Sorry, added link in the question @JachymMichal

Comment: Is it still for some NN learning?

Comment: @lemon yes, look at the background image [here](https://www.rijkzwaan.com/artificial-intelligence), it's almost impossible to manually label something like this, I'm looking for a solution that will solve this automatically

Comment: @cxnt, hard to know in this context how will react this kind of algorithm trained with fake images. Am I wrong? What are the key points in your opinion?

Comment: @lemon There are a lot of experiments ahead with synthetic data, most of my previous experiments were unpredictable until I actually trained some data, I couldn't see the result, and make any conclusion, to improve my nn model. I haven't tested yet the melon case, I'm gonna do it today, and see how it goes. I think this task is pretty similar to finding cracks on roads or cracks on buildings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a rough quick attempt.

Use a *Voronoi* texture set to *Distance to Edge* as base for the mask between the two colors.
Distort it with another smaller *Voronoi* texture to give the "cracks" a rougher look, by mixing "clean" texture coordinates with the texture using a *Mix RGB* node.

Adjust all progressions with color ramps, and you can use a final color ramp through

Use a similar voronoi based texture for bump.

[image]

Comment: Your node setup is awesome, thank you so much!